# How can I pass a value from an MVC ActionResult to an AJAX success callback function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, callback

I have an AJAX call made to the controller and would like to receive a value back from the controller to be used in the callback function so that I can trigger an event (in this case a Kendo Popup Window). I am having a hard time finding a working example online. Any help in solving this issue would be greatly appreciated.

My AJAX Call:

```
$("#SubmitButton").on("click", function () {

    $.ajax({
        url: "/Workflow/SaveWorkflow",
        type: 'POST',
        data: ({ buttonType: "Submit Form" }),
        success: function(data)
        {
            if (data.Multiple != null) {

                var window = $("#SelectUsers").data("kendoWindow");

                window.refresh({
                    url: ("Workflow", "SelectNextFormUsers"),
                    datatype: "json",
                    data: ({ formInstanceID: '@Model.FormInstanceID', userOption: 2 })
                });

                window.center();
                window.open();
            }
            else
            {
                //do nothing
            }
        }
    })
});
```

Where I am attempting to return the value in the controller (the controller returns an ActionResult):

```
if (nextformRule.UserOption != (int)UserOptions.AllUser)
{
    //return RedirectToAction("SelectNextFormUsers", new { forminstanceID = fmInst.FormInstanceID, userOption = nextformRule.UserOption });  //Send Email page

    //string result = "multiple";

    //return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    //return Content(result);

    return Json(new
    {
        Multiple = "multiple"
    });
}
```

Comment: what error do you get? in console or other http error?

Comment: no errors but the value is not sent to the success callback. It just displays a white screen with the string I passed in the upper left corner. I have an alert in the success callback function but it never gets initiated.

Comment: Can you show your `SaveWorkflow` method signature? Do you have `HttpPost` over it?

Answer (score 0):

I guess `#SubmitButton` is a regular submit button inside a `form` tag and when it's clicked the JavaScript click handler (and the corresponding ajax request) is executed, but the default behaviour of the button is not prevented. A regular form submit happen and you are receiving the JSON result which is shown by the browser.

You can try to prevent this default behaviour by using [`event.preventDefault`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) (recommended):

```
$("#SubmitButton").on("click", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    [ ... ]
});
```

Or by returning `false` at the end of the event handler:

```
$("#SubmitButton").on("click", function () {
    [ ... ]

    return false;
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but this is not the problem. The SaveWorkflow() method will either submit the form or interrupt the user with a popup window they must complete before submitting. If I prevent the default behavior, the first scenario where the form gets submitted will not be able to occur.

Comment: @MattParra. It **is** the problem. If you just seeing a new page with `{Multiple = "multiple"}`then you doing a normal submit in addition to the ajax call.

Comment: Well I can't prevent the default because it causes the function not to submit EVER and I need it to submit about 90% of the time. I think I have found a workaround and will update once I have it solved and working.

Comment: @MattParra I still think that this is the problem. Can you explain further and maybe add the `chtml` code and the `SaveWorkflow` method?